# CakePHP overload?

Tags: cakephp

It seems for me that objects in CakePHP are too much overloaded. I've output debug in my layout: `debug($this);` and I found 6 instances of HTML helper object:

```
[Html] => HtmlHelper Object
        ([tags] => Array
             ([meta] => <meta%s/>
              [metalink] => <link href="%s"%s/>
              [link] => <a href="%s"%s>%s</a>
              [mailto] => <a href="mailto:%s" %s>%s</a>
              [form] => <form %s>
              .........................................
              .........................................
```

Why is that and is it possible to reduce this quantity to 1 instance?

Comment: What would be the purpose in reducing that quantity?  Cake isn't really a good fit for performance or memory limited scenarios.  If that's a major concern, you might look to find another tool rather than trying to sharpen the current one.

Comment: The purpose would be to make cake faster of course. That is not a big deal for me now as for my projects the performance is acceptable but if it is easy to make the code better why not do it?

Answer (score 4):

It's likely they're all references to the same instance.

To prove that they are, you could modify the helper constructor to include your own debug trace.

Comment: Could you provide more specifics? Where can I find the helper constructor?

Comment: Look in `cake/libs/views/helpers/html.php`.

Comment: I have not found the __construct or similar method there. What did you mean by "helper constructor"?

Comment: If the `__construct` method isn't there, you're free to create one.  If there's any confusion as to what the html helper is or why it's here, check out the CakePHP book section 2.4.4 View Conventions http://book.cakephp.org/view/906/View-Conventions

Comment: You can found the _constructor of HtmlHelper in this file
`../lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php`
and it's constructor will call to supper class (Helper class)
`../lib/Cake/View/Helper.php`